# How to sort object with two criteria in Python3?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

[image: Alphabet Data List]

- The alphabet represent object in a list.
- Each alphabet has a center coordinate (x,y).
- The number represent its index in the list.

I want to sort the item into order [A, B, C, D]. So ...

```
if abs(A.y - B.y) < threshold:
    # sort by x coordinate
else:
    # sort by y coordinate
```

I can do this by manually checking the objects and swapping their position directly.

But how do I do this with Python3 `sorted(key=)` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a comparison function, then use `functools.cmp_to_key` to convert it into a key function:

```
# Given a threshold, return a function suitable for
# use by old cmp argument
def comparator(threshold):
    def compare(A, B):
        if abs(A.y - B.y) < threshold:
            return cmp(A.x, B.x)
        else:
            return cmp(A.y, B.y)
    return compare

from functools import cmp_to_key
my_cmp = comparator(0.6)  # Or whatever threshold you need
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=cmp_to_key(my_cmp))
```

Comment: beat me by a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the python3 documentation : [Sorting How To](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html) you would define a complex compare function, and then use functools.cmp_to_key to convert it to a key function :

This should work :

```
import functools
def comp_func(A,B):
    if abs(A.y - B.y) < threshold:
        return A.y - B.y # Sort by y co-ord
    else:
        return A.x - B.x # Sort by x co-ord

....
sorted(data, key=functools.cmp_to_key(comp_func))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda p: (p.x, p.y))
```

Comment: That doesn't take into account the threshold for the difference in `y` coordinates.